# Is there any benefit to having multiple recruitment radio beacons?

Tags: fallout-4

I want to populate my settlements faster, is there any purpose in placing multiple recruitment radio beacons in them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[No, the game only checks if there is a beacon in a settlement.](https://www.reddit.com/r/falloutsettlements/comments/405lk9/psa_settler_recruitment_and_raid_chances/)

Only happiness increases the chance.

Build bars ( lvl 3 restaurant) to get +40 happiness.

No new settlers will come if you have five settlers that are not assigned to anything.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the last bit? I'm pretty sure I have settlements that have more than 10 settlers at which I never assigned anyone to any task.

Comment: The link to the source is in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I didn't notice any difference when I built multiple towers, but I haven't properly tested it

Make sure you have excess food, water and defence (you need 1 food per person, 1 water per person, and 2 defence per person (so as to keep your defence rating equal to the sum of your food and water)) and people should start arriving fairly quickly

Also note that there's a population cap on each settlement, which is equal to 10 plus the number of points you have in the charisma SPECIAL attribute

Answer (score -2):

multiple beacons make no difference to the amount of people who will enter a settlement according to my testing in the ps4 version of fallout 4. only the amount of excess resources and happiness will increase it (given you already have one recruitment beacon)